# add placeholder dynamically vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

this is a part of my code.

```
    <input type="text" v-model="formData.end_date" name="end_date" v-validate="'required'"
           v-bind:class="{'input-error' : errors.has('end_date')}">
    <span v-show="errors.has('end_date')"
          style="position: absolute; font-size: .7em ; margin-right: 1em;color: rgb(214, 48, 49);">{{errors.first('end_date') }}</span>
</div>
```

how can I add placeholder dynamically when `error.has('end_date')` return true

I try `v-bind: placeholder`

Comment: You can also use <input :placeholder="[[ urlPlaceholder ]]">

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

1) Add a `computed` property to your component

```
computed: {
   placeholder() {
      return this.errors.has('end_date') ? 'Your placeholder text' : ''
   }
}
```

2) Bind to your computed placeholder property with `v-bind:placeholder="placeholder"`

Answer (score 0):

you can get that done by saying `:placeholder`. Is that not working for you ? In your try you have a space between v-bind:placeholder. I think you should not be having that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input
   type="text"
   v-model="FirstName"
   class="form-control"
   :placeholder="functionData"
/>

computed:{
   functionData(){
     return "Data"
  }
}
```